# Streambuilder - error after flutter migration - snapshot syntax

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I used this code bevor migration

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
              .ref()
              .child('user')
              .child(_userID)
              .onValue,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              _networkImageUrl = snapshot.data.snapshot.value["img"];
              return Text(_networkImageUrl.toString());
             } else {
               return Container();
            }
          }),
```

after "dart pub upgrade --null-safety" I get the error:

```
The property 'snapshot' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
```

I tried to fix it with "!" but it doesn't work, it keeps the same error

Comment: Could you show how you tried to fix it? Where did you add `!` does the error point somewhere else when you add it?

Comment: _networkImageUrl = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value["img"];  At this position, but I tried every other as well:-). It throws the error "The getter 'snapshot' isn't defined for the type 'Object'"

Comment: try giving your snapshot a value: `StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(...`

Comment: thank you that was the decisive hint, I have expanded it by var userDocument = snapshot.data as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
              _networkImageUrl = userDocument["img"];

Comment: Happy it got fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the code:

```
StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent>(
          stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
              .ref()
              .child('user')
              .child(_userID)
              .onValue,
          builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              Map<dynamic, dynamic> userDocument = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
              _networkImageUrl = userDocument["img"]
              return Text(_networkImageUrl.toString());
             } else {
               return Container();
            }
          }),
```

Thanks to @h8moss